# Coordinate not taking effect upon compilation in Spring Cloud Pipelines

Tags: spring, kubernetes, spring-cloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I am following this [tutorial](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-pipelines/single/spring-cloud-pipelines.html#jenkins-pipeline-k8s) and I am facing build failure in 'deploy to test' stage when this [repo](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/github-webhook-kubernetes) is compiled. The reason for failure is that `sc-pipelines.yml` defines `eureka` service with `coordinate: scpipelines/github-eureka:latest`, which is not getting compiled into the equivalent `target\k8s\eureka.yml`. The compiled yml is having `image: :` for container image. Could someone please help me on how to get this image value populated with `scpipelines/github-eureka:latest` ?

```
12:39:25 Logging in to Kubernetes API [kubernetes.default:443], with cluster name [gke_kubproject-210508_asia-south1-b_cluster-1] and user [default]
12:39:25 Cluster "gke_kubproject-210508_asia-south1-b_cluster-1" set.
12:39:25 User "default" set.

12:39:25 Context "gke_kubproject-210508_asia-south1-b_cluster-1" created.
12:39:25 Switched to context "gke_kubproject-210508_asia-south1-b_cluster-1".
12:39:25 CLI version
12:39:25 Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.2", GitCommit:"bb9ffb1654d4a729bb4cec18ff088eacc153c239", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-07T23:17:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
12:39:25 Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9+", GitVersion:"v1.9.7-gke.5", GitCommit:"9b635efce81582e1da13b35a7aa539c0ccb32987", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-02T23:42:40Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
12:39:25 Pipeline descriptor already parsed - will not parse it again
12:39:25 Deleting all possible entries with name [rabbitmq-github-webhook]
12:39:26 Error from server (NotFound): secrets "rabbitmq-github-webhook" not found
12:39:26 Error from server (NotFound): persistentvolumeclaims "rabbitmq-github-webhook" not found
12:39:26 Error from server (NotFound): pods "rabbitmq-github-webhook" not found
12:39:26 Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions "rabbitmq-github-webhook" not found

12:39:26 service "rabbitmq-github-webhook" deleted
12:39:26 Will deploy service with type [rabbitmq] name [rabbitmq-github-webhook] and coordinates []
12:39:26 Waiting for RabbitMQ to start
12:39:26 replicationcontroller "rabbitmq-github-webhook" deleted
12:39:26 Error from server (NotFound): error when deleting "target/k8s/rabbitmq-service.yml": services "rabbitmq-github-webhook" not found
12:39:26 Failed to delete app by [target/k8s/rabbitmq-service.yml] file. Continuing with the script
12:39:27 replicationcontroller/rabbitmq-github-webhook replaced
12:39:27 service/rabbitmq-github-webhook replaced
12:39:27 Deleting all possible entries with name [mysql-github-webhook]

12:39:27 secret "mysql-github-webhook" deleted
12:39:27 Error from server (NotFound): persistentvolumeclaims "mysql-github-webhook" not found
12:39:27 pod "mysql-github-webhook" deleted

12:39:44 Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions "mysql-github-webhook" not found

12:39:44 service "mysql-github-webhook" deleted
12:39:44 Will deploy service with type [mysql] name [mysql-github-webhook] and coordinates []
12:39:44 Waiting for MySQL to start
12:39:44 Generating secret with name [mysql-github-webhook]
12:39:45 Error from server (NotFound): secrets "mysql-github-webhook" not found
12:39:45 Failed to delete secret [mysql-github-webhook]. Continuing with the script
12:39:45 secret/mysql-github-webhook created
12:39:45 Error from server (NotFound): error when deleting "target/k8s/mysql.yml": pods "mysql-github-webhook" not found
12:39:45 Failed to delete app by [target/k8s/mysql.yml] file. Continuing with the script
12:39:45 Error from server (NotFound): error when deleting "target/k8s/mysql-service.yml": services "mysql-github-webhook" not found
12:39:45 Failed to delete app by [target/k8s/mysql-service.yml] file. Continuing with the script

12:39:45 pod/mysql-github-webhook replaced
12:39:46 service/mysql-github-webhook replaced
12:39:46 Deleting all possible entries with name [eureka-github-webhook]
12:39:46 Error from server (NotFound): secrets "eureka-github-webhook" not found
12:39:46 Error from server (NotFound): persistentvolumeclaims "eureka-github-webhook" not found

12:39:46 Error from server (NotFound): pods "eureka-github-webhook" not found
12:39:47 Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions "eureka-github-webhook" not found
12:39:47 Error from server (NotFound): services "eureka-github-webhook" not found
12:39:47 Will deploy service with type [eureka] name [eureka-github-webhook] and coordinates []
12:39:47 Deploying Eureka. Options - image name [:], app name [eureka-github-webhook], env [TEST]
12:39:47 error: error parsing target/k8s/eureka.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 13: mapping values are not allowed in this context
12:39:47 Failed to delete app by [target/k8s/eureka.yml] file. Continuing with the script
12:39:47 Error from server (NotFound): error when deleting "target/k8s/eureka-service.yml": services "eureka-github-webhook" not found
12:39:47 Failed to delete app by [target/k8s/eureka-service.yml] file. Continuing with the script

12:39:47 error: error parsing target/k8s/eureka.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 13: mapping values are not allowed in this context
12:39:47 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
12:39:47 Archiving artifacts
12:39:48 Finished: FAILURE
```

sc-pipelines.yml

```
test:
  # list of required services
  services:
    - type: rabbitmq
      name: rabbitmq-github-webhook
    - type: mysql
      name: mysql-github-webhook
      database: example
    - type: eureka
      name: eureka-github-webhook
      coordinates: scpipelines/github-eureka:latest
```

eureka.yml - Please notice the empty value for `image` key.

```
1 apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
 2 kind: Deployment
 3 metadata:
 4   name: eureka-github-webhook
 5 spec:
 6   replicas: 1 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
 7   template: # create pods using pod definition in this template
 8       metadata:
 9         labels:
10           name: eureka-github-webhook
11       spec:
12         containers:
13         - name: eureka-github-webhook
14           image: :
15           ports:
16           - containerPort: 8761
17           env:
18           - name: PORT
19             value: "8761"
20           - name: eureka_client_serviceUrl_defaultZone
21             value: "http://eureka-github-webhook.sc-pipelines-prod:8761/eureka/"
22           livenessProbe:
```

Comment: I notice you link to spring-cloud-samples/github-webhook-kubernetes but the guide says to fork that repo (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-pipelines/single/spring-cloud-pipelines.html#fork-repos-k8s). Would be better to link to your fork if you can (unless it's a private repo).

Comment: My forked repo is at https://github.com/guptamahcl/github-webhook-kubernetes. I am using the forked one in jenkins.

Comment: Are you trying to push the image to public dockerhub?

Comment: Can you print the logs from executing the deployment step? We will get to the bottom of this!

Comment: @RyanDawson: Yes

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak: added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-pipelines/issues/187. Please try again using the latest commits from the master branch